# Need to display tier price range on recently viewed products widget

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I need to display the tier price min and max value in recently viewed products widget instead of regular price. It seems completely UI components involved. I found the file where I can see the component and html template.

```
<item name="regular_price" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Regular Price</item>
   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/product/list/columns/final-price</item>
   <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/product/price/regular_price</item>
   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">2</item>
</item>
```

in vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\ui_component\widget_recently_viewed.xml

As I checked the model file,

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getPriceInfo()
{
    return $this->getData('price_info');
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function setPriceInfo(PriceInfoInterface $priceInfo)
{
    $this->setData('price_info', $priceInfo);
}
```

in vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\ProductRender.php.

As part of **price info** I need to send and set tier price as well. Because, **price info** does not render tier price. If it is set then I can able to display them through html file.

How can I display tier price value as range instead of regular price. Like below screenshot.

[image]